# Given $f_X(x)$ find the pdf $f_Z(z)$ when $Z = X^2$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have a question on probability density function. I cannot get the value for interval so I'm not sure if I did it the right way:

[image]

[image]

My answer:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Because $X=\sqrt{Z}$ you should have used: $$F_Z(z) = f_X(\sqrt z) \left\lvert \dfrac{\mathrm d \sqrt z}{\mathrm d~z}\right\rvert\quad\mathbf 1_{z\in(0;16)}$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp 
 
On the question it said "Z = X^2" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $X=\sqrt{Z}$ you should have used: $$\begin{align}f_Z(z) ~=~& f_X(\sqrt z) \left\lvert \dfrac{\mathrm d \sqrt z}{\mathrm d~z}\right\rvert\quad\mathbf 1_{z\in(0;16)}
\\[1ex] ~=~& \dfrac{1}{4\sqrt[4]{z~}}\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt z}\quad\mathbf 1_{z\in(0;16)}\\[1ex]=~& \tfrac 1 8 z^{-3/4}\quad\mathbf 1_{z\in(0;16)}\end{align}$$

---

Note: as remarked by Ian, care has to be used with change of variables when the transformation involves folds (ie: it is not one-to-one over the support).   Fortunately that is not the case here.

Comment: On the question it said "Z = X^2" ?

Comment: @KrinYongvongphaiboon $Z=X^2 \iff X=\sqrt Z$ (when $X$ is strictly non-negative).

Comment: Oh I got it! Thank you!

Comment: What is number 1 in front of interval of Z for?

Comment: @KrinYongvongphaiboon It is an Indicator variable. $$\mathbf 1_{z\in A}=\begin{cases} 1 & : z\in A\\ 0 & :z\notin A\end{cases}$$ Sometimes written as an [Indicator Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function): $\mathbf 1_A(z)$ or using the [Iverson Bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) notation: $\Big[z\in A\Big]$

Comment: The next question ask me to find E(z) so basically I just gonna use the function above to find the integral from 0 < Z < 16 right?

Comment: Yes. @KrinYongvongphaiboon  $\mathsf E(Z)=\int_0^{16} z~f_Z(z)\operatorname d z$

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you please help me with one more? I'm so sorry to bother you. The question ask to find E(3x + 5). This means I have do the integral from 0 < x < 4 of (3x + 4)fx dx. Is that right?

Comment: @KrinYongvongphaiboon Yes; but notice that: $\mathsf E(3X+5)= 3\mathsf E(X)+5 = 5+\frac 3 4\int_0^4 x^{1/2}\operatorname d x$

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that everything should actually be back in terms of $z$, not in terms of $x$. Consequently, the way you have proceeded, you have obtained a "density" that cannot be integrated (the integral would be $+\infty$).

I prefer to do these kinds of problems by computing $F_Z$ and differentiating rather than directly computing $f_Z$. This also correctly deals with what happens when the function $g$ such that $Z=g(X)$ is not one-to-one. For instance this would happen if your $X$ had a density of $\frac{1}{8} |x|^{-1/2}$ for $x$ between $-4$ and $4$ and $Z$ was still $X^2$.

To do that, you have

$$F_Z(z)=\begin{cases} 0 & z<0 \\
1 & z>16 \\
\int_0^{z^{1/2}} \frac{1}{4} x^{-1/2} dx & 0 \leq z \leq 16.\end{cases}$$

Then

$$f_Z(z)=\begin{cases} \frac{d}{dz} \left ( \int_0^{z^{1/2}} \frac{1}{4} x^{-1/2} dx \right ) & 0 \leq z \leq 16 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$

Note that you can use the fundamental theorem of calculus to compute $f_Z$ without having an explicit formula for $F_Z$ (though in this particular case it is easy to get an explicit formula for $F_Z$).

Looking over the result of this calculation, you can see that the problem in your calculation is that you should have $f_X(x(z)) \frac{1}{2x(z)}$ where $x(z)=z^{1/2}$. But even this alone would not work in the case I mentioned before, where a given value of $Z$ does not correspond to a unique value of $X$.

Answer (score 0):

As is the case here the transformation $z = g(x) = x^2$ is one-to-one over the support and has the inverse transformation

$$x = g^{-1}(z) = h(z) = \sqrt{z}$$

and then as already has been said in the other answers the pdf of $Z$ is given by

$$f_Z(z) = f_X(x)\left|\frac{dx}{dz}\right| = f_X[h(z)]\left|\frac{dh(z)}{dz}\right| = f_X[\sqrt{z}]\left|\frac{d\sqrt{z}}{dz}\right| \:\:\:\:\:(1)$$

In the general case, i.e. when you are not so lucky that it is one-to-one over the support it gets a little bit more complicated.

Denoting the real roots of $z = g(x)$ by $x_k$ then

$$f_Z(z) = \sum_k \frac{f_X(x_k)}{|g'(x_k)|} \:\:\:\:\: (2)$$

In this case with $z = g(x) = x^2:$

If $z<0$, then the equation $z = x^2$ has no real solutions; hence, $f_Z(z)=0$.

If $z>0$, then $z=x^2$ has two solutions, $x_1 = \sqrt{z}$ and $x_2 = -\sqrt{z}$.

Further we have $g'(x)=2x$. Hence by the transformation of variables formula $(2)$:
$$
f_Z(z) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{z}}\left[f_X(\sqrt{z}) + f_X(-\sqrt{z})\right],  & z>0 \\
0, & z<0 
\end{cases}
$$